# What method is called from the backstack

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, back-stack

What method gets called when an `Activity` is shown again from the backstack after a BackPress on a previous activity. I've tried the onActivityReenter but it doesn't get called as I expected.

Comment: Take a look here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html